# Open a pdf stored in internal storage through an Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open a pdf I created in internal storage in a directory.

I even checked in debugger the open pdf code and the Uri and everything is correct but the StartActivity(Intent) fails. Please could someone guide me what maybe the issue?

```
lvListorder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Invoice_RestoManager/Order-20190726_014706.pdf");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent1.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent1);
           }
    });
```

I expect the pdfviewer app to open the pdf when this intent gets executed.
Right now the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by following the following method.
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0